# Spark read column contents from distinct file per row

Tags: java, apache-spark, file-io

I'm using Java 11 with Spark 3.3.0. I have a list of IDs `ids.lst`. Then in each sub directory `{id}/{id}-data.txt` I have  extra data I want to load.

I can pretend `ids.lst` is a CSV file with a single column and load it using the following. (So that I can understand the concept, you can assume that I'm loading data off my own machine in "local" mode using Java NIO.)

```
Dataset<Row> ids = spark.read().format("csv").option("header", "false")
    .load("ids.lst");
```

That gives me something like:

```
+----+
| id |
+----|
| 1  |
| 2  |
| 3  |
| …  |
+----+
```

Now how do I load the per-row data? I want to wind up with:

```
+----+--------------------------+
| id | data                     |
+----+--------------------------|
| 1  | data from `1/1-data.txt` |
| 2  | data from `2/2-data.txt` |
| 3  | data from `3/3-data.txt` |
| …  | …                        |
+----+--------------------------+
```

The next step is that I want to extract information from the `data` column *using some complex custom code* and place it in yet a third column. Would I use the same technique? Or would I use a UDF? Or would in fact the loading of this `data` column simply be I/O code that I placed in a UDF?

Comment: Is [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#input_file_name) of any help to you?

Comment: No, it is not of any help to me.